# K-fold cross-validation vs split-sample cross-validation (i.e., 2-fold cross-validation)

Tags: cross-validation

I am doing a preperation for the exam and I am confronted with this question, can you tell me, which solutions are right?

a. Split-sample cross-validation is a biased estimate of model fit.

b. Split-sample cross-validation is too noisy to be useful in practice.

c. K-fold cross-validation is a low-variance estimate of model fit.

d. Increasing the number of folds increases statistical power.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: Since this is a study question, it will be more useful for us to help you think through through the process instead of giving answers. Perhaps you could edit your question to indicate which answer you think is correct and, most importantly, why. Or, add a sentence under each possibility indicating why you think it might be correct / incorrect.